# Update combobox after insert a value

Tags: vb.net

I want to update the Combobox after insert a value that goes straight into the Combobox. Probably I need to make a query and I already got it. That is the code that I got at the moment

```
    Private Sub UpdateComboBox()
    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "...."
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT Filetype FROM infofile GROUP BY Filetype"
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        SQLDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ComboBox1.Items.Add(Query)
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

and I want to add this method at the moment after insert something.

This code is in the form

```
SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "......"
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "SELECT Filetype FROM infofile GROUP BY Filetype"
            SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
            SQLDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
            While SQLDataReader.Read
                Dim fileType = SQLDataReader.GetString(0)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ComboBox1.Items.Add(fileType)
            End While
            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            SQLCon.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Comment: combobox1.update() ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Private Sub UpdateComboBox()
    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "....."
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT Filetype FROM infofile GROUP BY Filetype"
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(table)
        ComboBox1.DataSource = table
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Filetype"
        SQLCon.Close()
        Return table
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This is actually working. But this updates on my ComboBox and and the datagridview and I dont want it

Comment: you must not put this code in the same function FillDataGriwView.

Comment: i you call this method the only Combobox was updated!

Comment: But I don't want to do anything on the DataGridView just on the ComboBox

Comment: are you affect the combobox datasource to datagridview like : `DataGridView1.DataSource =  ComboBox1.DataSource` or something like that

Comment: Yes. I got something like that but I need it. What should I do?

Comment: i change you code, can you test it! you must separate Datasource of ech control `ComboBox` and `DataGridView`

Comment: I want to separate this 2 things. I just want to update the combo box without showing anything on the datagridview.

Comment: The `DataGridView` updated when you update then `ComboBox` because, you assign a DataSource to `DataGridView` in event `SelectedIndexChanged` of `ComboBox`. i have change code in answer, you can test it.

Comment: That Return table gave me an error: "Return statement in a Sub or a Set cannot return a value"